# PyQtWebEngine in Full Screen is Flash screen

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

In full screen,the PyQtWebEngineView is splash screen. This has seriously affected the user experience. I try searching to solve this problem.

But only can search for C/C++ Qt5 for code:

```
QWindowsWindowFunctions::setHasBorderInFullScreen(windowHandle(), true)
```

although can,but not in python.

How to in PyQt5 solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution!

https://programmersought.com/article/45012964151/

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL, True)

    MainUI = YourQMainWindowClass()
    MainUI.showFullScreen()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```